# using only currentTimeMillis() to get the date

Tags: java, time

So I'm totaly lost. I have to print out the actual Date and time using only `currentTimeMillis()` and nothing else. Getting the time was no problem:

```
long t = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();

long seconds = (t / 1000) % 60;
long minutes = (t / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
long hours = (t / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24) + zone;
```

But how can I calculate the date taking leap years into consideration?

Edit: It's homework, hence this weird question. And we are not allowed to use any other methodes besides currentTimeMillis(). Operators and alike are fine.

Comment: every 4-th year is leap, so what the problem?

Comment: what is the variable zone's value ?

Comment: I think zone is time zone in hours.

Comment: Note that some time zones (in India, for instance) have 30 minute offsets. This problem is *hard* to get right in a general case. Why are you not able to use a pre-existing library implementation?

Comment: @VDanyliuk: No, that's wrong. Still, it nicely starts to show the complexity of the problem...

Comment: @VDanyliuk 2000 was not a leap year.

Comment: Also, there are leap seconds, so your seconds are wrong.

Comment: @Manu 2000 was a leap year, but 1900 was not :P every 100 years a leap year is ommited but every 400 years you do have one ;)

Comment: Also don't forget the leap seconds!

Comment: @ParkerHalo Oh, I just thought we skipped one every 100th year. Cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the timezone related problem, following fix can be used. However this is just one case: other cases need to be handled as well.

```
//let's say time zone is +5:30
long zone = 6; //instead of 5, keeping value 6, thus added extra 30 minutes
long minuten = (t / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
long stunden = (t / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24) + zone;
if(minuten < 30){ // this is to take care of the cases where hour has moved ahead
    stunden--;
    minuten+=30;
} else{
    minuten-=30; // else deduct those additional 30 minutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without using *anything else*. You have to be more clear about which restrictions there are and why? Is this homework?

The simplest way I can think of is:

```
long t = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(new Date(t));
```

But I am sure that's not what you need. Please elaborate...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10303112)

Comment: It is a partial answer. In a comment I could not easily have given the code example I provided. Also, I intend to provide a full answer once extra information arrives.

Comment: I really dont know what the point of this task is. It would be no problem if we'd be allowed to use other methods. It's more of a mathematical problem.

Comment: So you are allowed to use math operators? What else are you allowed to use?

Comment: Maybe i was not precise enough. I'm not allowed to use any other method. Operators are all fine afaik.